# JSSOR - element thumbnailtemplate not allowed as child of element div in this context.

Tags: jssor

I am using a jquery plugin for an image slider on my website. however when testing the website it is saying that "element thumbnailtemplate not allowed as child of element div in this context."

This is the html snippet including the element

```
        <div data-u="slides" style="cursor: move;">
            <div data-u="prototype" class="p" style="position: absolute; width: 99px; height: 66px; top: 0; left: 0;">
                <div class=w><thumbnailtemplate style=" width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none;position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0;"></thumbnailtemplate></div>
                <div class=c>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

now the files are too big to include all in this question. but in the jssor.slider.js file it has the following javascript

```
    //NavigationItem Constructor
    {
        _Thumbnail = item.$Thumb || item.$Image || $JssorUtils$.$CreateDivElement();
        self.$Wrapper = _Wrapper = $JssorUtils$.$BuildElement(_ThumbnailPrototype, "ThumbnailTemplate", _Thumbnail, true);

        _Button = $JssorUtils$.$Buttonize(_Wrapper);
        if (_Options.$ActionMode & 1)
            $JssorUtils$.$AddEvent(_Wrapper, "click", OnNavigationRequest);
        if (_Options.$ActionMode & 2)
            $JssorUtils$.$AddEvent(_Wrapper, "mouseover", OnNavigationRequest);
    }
```

hiow can i get arround this so that my website validates as per w3c validator

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been fixed, please download the latest version and replace

```
<div class=w><thumbnailtemplate style=" width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none;position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0;"></thumbnailtemplate>
```

with

```
<div u="thumbnailtemplate" style=" width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none;position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0;"></div>
```